# Select rows from table1 and all the children from table2 into an object

Tags: c#, linq, join

I want to pull data from table "Province_Notifiers" and also fetch all corresponding items from table "Province_Notifier_Datas". The table "Province_Notifier" has a guid to identify it (PK), table "Province_Notifier_Datas" has a column called BelongsToProvinceID witch is a foreign key to the "Province_Notifier" tables guid.

I tried something like this:

```
var records = from data in ctx.Province_Notifiers
              where DateTime.Now >= data.SendTime && data.Sent == false
              join data2 in ctx.Province_Notifier_Datas on data.Province_ID equals data2.BelongsToProvince_ID
              select new Province_Notifier
              {
                  Email = data.Email,
                  Province_ID = data.Province_ID,
                  ProvinceName = data.ProvinceName,
                  Sent = data.Sent,
                  UserName = data.UserName,
                  User_ID = data.User_ID,
                  Province_Notifier_Datas = (new List<Province_Notifier_Data>().AddRange(data2))
              };
```

This line is not working and i am trying to figure out how topull the data from table2 into that Province_Notifier_Datas variable.

```
Province_Notifier_Datas = (new List<Province_Notifier_Data>().AddRange(data2))
```

I can add a record easily by adding the second table row into the Province_Notifier_Datas but i can't fetch it back.

```
Province_Notifier dbNotifier = new Province_Notifier();
// set some values for dbNotifier
dbNotifier.Province_Notifier_Datas.Add(
          new Province_Notifier_Data
          {
              BelongsToProvince_ID = userInput.Value.ProvinceId,
              EventText = GenerateNotificationDetail(notifierDetail)
          });
```

This works and inserts the data correctly into both tables.

**Edit:**

These error messages is thrown:

> Cannot convert from 'Province_Notifier_Data' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'

If i look in Visual Studio, the variable "Province_Notifier_Datas" is of type System.Data.Linq.EntitySet

> The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List.AddRange(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)' has some invalid arguments

**Edit**:

```
var records = from data in ctx.Province_Notifiers
              where DateTime.Now >= data.SendTime && data.Sent == false        
              join data2 in ctx.Province_Notifier_Datas on data.Province_ID equals data2.BelongsToProvince_ID
              into data2list
              select new Province_Notifier
              {
                  Email = data.Email,
                  Province_ID = data.Province_ID,
                  ProvinceName = data.ProvinceName,
                  Sent = data.Sent,
                  UserName = data.UserName,
                  User_ID = data.User_ID,
                  Province_Notifier_Datas = new EntitySet<Province_Notifier_Data>().AddRange(data2List)
              };
```

Error 3 The name 'data2List' does not exist in the current context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data2` represents a single object of type `Province_Notifier_Data`, not an enumeration (therefore the exception). Try to insert an `into` clause into your query:

```
var records = from data in ctx.Province_Notifiers
              where DateTime.Now >= data.SendTime && data.Sent == false
              join data2 in ctx.Province_Notifier_Datas
                  on data.Province_ID equals data2.BelongsToProvince_ID
              into data2List
              select new Province_Notifier
              {
                  Email = data.Email,
                  Province_ID = data.Province_ID,
                  ProvinceName = data.ProvinceName,
                  Sent = data.Sent,
                  UserName = data.UserName,
                  User_ID = data.User_ID,
                  Province_Notifier_Datas = data2List
              };
```

If `Province_Notifier_Datas` is of type `EntitySet<T>` you could try the following: Define an extension method (idea from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/linqprojectgeneral/thread/58c4dcf8-2d89-4a3c-bb30-58c7c15df04b)):

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static EntitySet<T> ToEntitySet<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
        where T : class
    {
        var entitySet = new EntitySet<T>();
        entitySet.AddRange(source);
        return entitySet;
    }
}
```

And then replace the last line by:

```
Province_Notifier_Datas = data2List.ToEntitySet()
```

Comment: When i try that i get the following error:

Error 3 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Province_Notifier_Data>' to 'System.Data.Linq.EntitySet<Province_Notifier_Data>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: @Patrick: Is `Province_Notifier_Datas` of type `EntitySet<T>`? Then try my edited code.

Comment: I added that, but now it can't find the data2List ?? Se my post above, at the bottom

Comment: Seems to be a typo: `data2list` vs. `data2List`

Comment: Yea, im blind sometimes. I got this now: Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Data.Linq.EntitySet<Province_Notifier_Data>'

Comment: Sorry, yes, this could not compile. I have changed the code, see my answer.